# Does $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$ always hold when $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables. The standard proof for
$$E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)\tag{$\ast$}\label{exy}$$
either uses
$$E(X)=\sum_xxf(x)$$
if $f(x)$ is a pmf of $X$, or
$$E(X)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x)\,dx$$
if $f(x)$ is a pdf of $X$. But what if $X$ or $Y$ is a continuous random variable without pdf? Does \eqref{exy} still hold, provided that $E(XY)$, $E(X)$, and $E(Y)$ all exist?

Comment: Yes, it always holds. It is an application of Fubini's Theorem.

Comment: What is your definition of independence? Sometimes $\mathbb{E}(f(X) g(Y)) = \mathbb{E}(f(X)) \mathbb{E}(g(Y))$ for a suitable class of functions is taken as the definition of independence in which case this is true by definition.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan I'm using the standard definition: $X$ and $Y$ are independent if $P(X\in A,\ Y\in B)=P(X\in A)P(Y\in B)$ for all Borel sets $A,B\subseteq\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: By your definition isn't it clear that $$\sum_{x,y} xyP(x\in A,y\in B)=\sum_{x,y} xyP(x\in A)P(y\in B)$$ factorizes?

Comment: It's true in general, provided $E(X)$ and $E(Y)$ exist.

Comment: Just note that $P(X\in A)=\int_A dF_X$, therefore from the definition of independence we find that $dF_{X,Y}=dF_X\, dF_Y$, that is, $dF_{X,Y}$ is just a product measure, therefore the result follows.

Comment: @Diger It is clear if the sum if finite.

Comment: I'm not saying anything about finiteness...

Comment: @Diger I see. You mean Fubini's theorem? My understanding is that the series version of Fubini's theorem (or Tonelli's theorem) holds for nonnegative series, but not in general.